# Update div on load with new content (refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I am loading an html page within another using div and changing the html like this:

```
$("#mirador").load("mirador.html", function(){
        $("#mirador #loadedManifest").html("http://localhost:3001/api/manifests/"+searchReq);
    });
```

`searchReq` is coming from a drop down.

The first time I do it it works well but if I change the `searchReq` from the drop down the div is not refreshed. Any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: Do you have an eventhandler attached to the dropdown (select-element) that will trigger on change? There is no indication of that in your code. Also does the html returned by that api always return an element with the id you are looking for?

Comment: you need to bind a change event handler to the search req drop down that would run the code when you change the value

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach it to an event handler ( dropdown `onChange` )

like below :

```
$("yourDropDownSelector").on("change",function(e){

    // the above depends on which dropdown you're using ,so here just e.target.value as a sample
    var searchReq = e.target.value;

    $("#mirador").load("mirador.html", function(){
         $("#mirador #loadedManifest").html("http://localhost:3001/api/manifests/"+searchReq);
    });
})
```